# Off-limit memory locations in C

Tags: c, memory

Is this code valid C:

```
fputc(*("Checking 7 bytes before this string"-7), stdout);
```

Is there anything in the C standard against doing this? i.e reading a couple of bytes before a string literal. What about this: (assuming that these locations actually exist for the process)

```
for (i=(char *)0x400000; i<(char *)0x400800; ++i) fputc(*i, stdout);
```

If these are valid, are there any off-limit memory locations in C?

Thank you.

Comment: It's an "undefined" situation.  Could work, could cause the end of the universe as we know it.

Comment: Off-limits means off limits. It doesn't matter what the language is.

Comment: This would be UB, there is no one explanation for this, it depends on your kernel.

Comment: This will cause warp core breach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first will result in undefined behavior, as you are going out of the boundaries of the string literal (underflow)

The second is example is undefined as well, as you access address that are not guaranteed to be accessible, or even exist.

The off-limit memory locations are not of C, but of the OS and the compiler.

Comment: Actually they are off-limits for C too, because the language definition states semantics for pointer dereferences only within "objects".   Addresses which were not returned by malloc and which are not inside live defined objects are not pointers to "objects" in the sense of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Modern processors use what's known as protected memory. So your process has its own slice of memory.

The memory model in C uses has a stack, which is used to keep track of what function has called what, with what local variables and parameters. When you put 'int x;' at the beginning of a function, that goes on the stack.

There is also the heap. The heap is all of the dynamic memory - all the malloc() and new() that go on.

There's also "hidden" memory - memory used by various library, support, etc. programs.

When you pass that argument to fputc, it's possible that you'll be passing some of the stack; it's more likely, since that's a string constant, that you'll be passing padding or some executable code.

Now, being a protected-memory system, your process thinks it has memory starting at byte 0. It gets its own flat memory space to diddle around in. But things aren't quite that simple; it's very easy to read/write outside what is currently apportioned, which on a modern operating system should simply cause a memory exception that will halt your program.

Is there anything AGAINST doing the first thing? No. Is it safe to do if you're just curious what might be there? Sure, but there are better ways to look. Are there about a million reasons you should never, ever do that in code? Yes.

As to the second thing, assuming those addresses are mapped in your program, you may get any of the data - program code, heap memory, (probably not stack memory), anything really. There's nothing specifically against it and as long as you're just reading it, the worst you'll get is a segfault (memory exception).

But there is never, ever any reason to do this. If you're simply curious, any competent compiler suite (gcc, MSVC++, etc.) will allow you to do a core dump, or even step through and examine the heap and stack during execution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

_"but there are better ways to look"_ 
Could you mention one?

Comment: Sorry, by "better ways to look" I meant use a debugger. I'm not sure what platform/compiler you're using but there are many ways depending on what you have.

Answer (score 1):

They are valid C, syntax is fine, compiler will allow it. You are suppose to be able to shoot yourself in the foot.

Runtime error is different business, first example most likely will work, -7 byte offset the literal most likely still in the same segment. Second example may or may not work, depends on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, there is no "memory limits" for a C program. However, most applications run in user mode, and they are limited by the operating system because the O.S. runs in kernel mode and it imposes limitations so all the applications could run in their own memory space.

So, when a user mode application tries to access a non-authorized memory address, an exception is raised.

On the other hand, if the program uses some O.S. bug to get kernel mode... Well, that's the way viruses, trojans and other malwares are created ;)